# Hiding status bar does not work for all devices

Tags: android, statusbar

I have tried several things in order to hide the status bar in my app. It seems to work, but several users complain they still see the status bar. So, it looks like all proper solutions I have used, do not cover all devices/settings.

Here are the things I already added to my project:

In the `AndroidManifest`:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

In the `onCreate()` method:

```
requestWindowFeature( Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE );
getWindow().setFlags( WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN );
getWindow().getDecorView().requestLayout();
```

Now, this does work for almost all of my users. But some of them still see the status bar, even Galaxy S2 and S3 users (NOT ALL!).

Are there any other options left that I could try?

Comment: have you added your _Fullscreen_ code before `setContentView()` inside `onCreate()`?

Answer (score 0):

Try using only the Java code in `onCreate()` without the `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"`.

Put the Java code to the beginning of your `onCreate()`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```